# How can I store JavaScript from within a jQuery [each] loop to a php variable

Tags: php, jquery, each

I am [successfully] storing a snippet of jQuery inside a php variable, with values inside the snippet being populated by php script like so:

```
...//collect necessary variables

$script = "
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($) {
      analytics.identity('" . $cid . "', {
        created: '" . $created . "',
        email: '" . $email . "',
        ...: '" . $whatever . "'
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
";

return $script;
```

I can also [successfully] get the name attribute of all forms on the page like so:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($) {
      $('form').each(function() {
        var formname = $( this ).attr('name');
        if(formname !== undefined) {
          console.log(index + ':' + encodeURIComponent(formname));
        };
      });
    })(Jquery);
</script>
```

The problem I'm having (maybe obviously) is the lack of experience with javascript to know how to incorporate the two so my `$script` would look like so:

```
$script = "
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($) {
      analytics.identity('" . $cid . "', {
        created: '" . $created . "',
        email: '" . $email . "',
        ...: '" . $whatever . "'
      });
      analytics.trackForm($('form[name="formname1"]'),'Form Submitted', {
        lead: formname
      });
      analytics.trackForm($('form[name="formname2"]'),'Form Submitted', {
        lead: formname
      });
      ...//(n) number of form names
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
";
```

Latest script added directly to the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($) {
   $('form').each(function() {
    var formname = $(this).attr('name');
    if( formname !== undefined) {
      console.log( formname );
      var forms = $('form[name="' + formname + '"]');
      var trackforms = analytics.trackForm(forms, 'Submitted Optin Form', { leadmagnet: "'" + formname + '"' });
      return trackforms;
    }
   });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Console.log outputs the one form currently on the page, and if I add another, it outputs that correctly also, but the rest of the code is simply written as is and I'm not getting it.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.write(...)` is adding the string to the document not to the script.

You need to return the functions you want.

```
$script = "
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($) {
      analytics.identify('" . $ifs_id . "', {
        created: '" . $created . "',
        email: '" . $email . "',
        firstName: '" . $first_name . "',
        leadsource: '" . $lead_source ."'
      });
      $('form').each(function( index ) {
        var formname = $( this ).attr('name');
        if( formname !== undefined) {
          //console.log( index + ':' + formname );
          var forms = $('form[name=\"+formname+\"]);
          var trackform = analytics.trackForm(forms, 'Submitted Opt In Form', {
             leadmagnet : $( this ).attr('name')
           });
          return trackform;

        }
      });
    })(jQuery);
   </script>
";

return $script;
```

Comment: Does the `trackform` need to be enclosed in quotes so it returns it as a string, because that's not working...

Comment: No. When the loop runs it goes through each form ... and then returns the function `analytics.trackForm(...)`.

Comment: I am missing something...it's adding it to the string and not outputting the variables

Comment: Still not working...

I added the snippet not working directly on the page and it's simply outputting the script, not the expected results of the loop - help!

Comment: It's adding this text to the php string. But when the browser loads the page with this javascript it runs the loop which runs the `analytics.trackForm(...)` function. You won't see the output of the form names etc. in the loop but you don't need the see it. It's running the loop and the function.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Guess I should have tested all the way through.